# WordPress /page/2 not working

Tags: query-posts, nextpage

When clicking the next_posts_link it just shows the same posts as on page 1. It appears to work fine on the category pages and it is only affecting the homepage (home.php)

Thanks!

```
    <?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; ?>
<?php query_posts('cat=-683,-3598' . $paged); ?>
```

---

FULL CODE

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>
    <div id="featured">
            <div id="featured_left">
                <div id="block1">
                <?php query_posts('cat=3598&showposts=1'); ?>
<?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php the_post_thumbnail('fbox12'); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

                </div>
                <div id="block2">
                <?php query_posts('cat=3598&showposts=1&offset=1'); ?>
<?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php the_post_thumbnail('fbox12'); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="featured_middle">
                <div id="block3">
                <?php query_posts('cat=3598&showposts=1&offset=2'); ?>
<?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php the_post_thumbnail('fbox3'); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

                </div>
                <div id="block6">
                <?php query_posts('cat=3598&showposts=1&offset=3'); ?>
<?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php the_post_thumbnail('fbox67'); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

                </div>
                <div id="block7">
                <?php query_posts('cat=3598&showposts=1&offset=4'); ?>
<?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php the_post_thumbnail('fbox67'); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="featured_right">
                <div id="block4">
                <?php query_posts('cat=3598&showposts=1&offset=5'); ?>
<?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php the_post_thumbnail('fbox45'); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

                </div>



            </div>
        </div>


        <div id="left">
        <?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; ?>
   <?php query_posts('cat=-683,-3598&paged=' . $paged); ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <div class="post_item">
        <?php
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('homepage-thumb'); ?></a>
<?php }
else { ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/no_thumb.png"/></a>
<?php }
?>
        <h2><?php the_category(', '); ?> | <?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?></h2>
        <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></a>
                </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="pagenav">
<div class="pagenavright"><?php next_posts_link('Next Entries','') ?></div>
</div> <!-- end navigation -->          
        </div>

    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

    </div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Don't use `query_posts`, ever](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts).

The first 6 queries can be condensed to a single `WP_Query`:

```
$args = array(
    'cat' => 3598,
    'posts_per_page' => 6
);

$featured = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $featured->have_posts() ){

    $featured->the_post();
    ?>
    your markup for the first post
    <?php

    $featured->the_post();
    ?>
    your markup for the second post
    <?php

    $featured->the_post();
    // etc..

    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

For the main query, use the [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action with a function in your theme's `functions.php`. This avoids wasting a query when you overwrite it in the template.

```
function wpa_exclude_categories( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'category__not_in', array( 683, 3598 ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpa_exclude_categories' );
```

You've now chopped 6 queries from every page load, and your pagination will magically work, do a little dance.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php query_posts('cat=-683,-3598' . $paged); ?>
```

This line should be

```
<?php query_posts('cat=-683,-3598&paged=' . $paged); ?>
```

Comment: Still not working.

Comment: Can you post full code of homepage template here ?

Comment: Added to the post above. Cheers!

Comment: Appears to be becuase of multiple query_posts

Comment: Use wp_reset_query();  after each query & try replacing the last query with 
query_posts('cat=-683,-3598&posts_per_page=3&paged=' . $paged);

Comment: [don't use `query_posts`, ever.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts)